# addPointerPressedListener not working on Table

Tags: codenameone

I have a table component in my form with lots of values. I want a pop up on clicking on each cell in the table to show some information. I wrote a code for that :

```
dataTable.addPointerPressedListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    Label c = (Label) dataTable.getClosestComponentTo(evt.getX(), evt.getY());
                    Dialog.show("Artifact", information, "Ok", null);
                }
            });
```

This method only works for last row and last column only and also not picking the right cell (closest cell). What I want is to pick the right cell on clicking in the table. What are the alternatives for doing this ?

I tried another way to do so. Code is

```
    @Override
    public void addPointerPressedListener(ActionListener l) {
         l = new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         Label c = (Label) getClosestComponentTo(evt.getX(), evt.getY());
         Dialog.show("Popup", c.getText(), "Ok", null);
        }
    };
        super.addPointerPressedListener(l);
    }
```

Both way I am getting problem. Its working on outer cells and at specific points only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table is a `Container` in which each cell is a component in its own right. To track an individual cell you can override the `createCell` method in table and track the component returned from there.

Comment: But addPointerPressedListener still not working. Same case again. Any suggestions ?

Comment: If you want a global pointer listener use the form not the container. Otherwise you need to use an individual component. Normally pointer events are problematic (e.g. you are probably wrong in overriding pointer pressed) I suggest you explain your end goal and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: In simplest case lets say, click on any column in the Table and a Dialog box will popup with some additional information. I don't want to change any data or add or remove component. I want listener only on the table. There are few other components in the form for which listener is not needed.

Comment: * not any column in the table instead any cell in the Table

Comment: Then just override the createCell to return a button instead of a label and add an action listener to the button. Make sure to give it a sensible UIID like TableCell and set its value correctly. That's what the method is there for.